# Find User Attribute from $_SERVER[Remote_User] - LDAP Query

Tags: php, ldap

When a user logs into my internal site, I would like to query LDAP to find their location based upon OU. Here is my code:

```
<?php                                     
$ldap_host = "LDAP Server";
$username="Username";
$password="password";
$ldap_dn = "OU=OU,OU=OU,DC=php,DC=co"; 
$attr = array("physicalDeliveryOfficeName"); #filter for location

# Fix Username to exclude "Domain\"
$user = $_SERVER[REMOTE_USER];
$ua =  ltrim($user, 'Domain\\');  

# LDAP Connection
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host) or die("Could not connect to LDAP");
@ldap_bind($ldap, $username , $password) or die("Could not bind to LDAP");

# Search Time.... search for attribute physicalDeliveryOfficeName
$search = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, "cn='$ua'", $attr); #filter correct?
$results = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $search);
echo $results["count"]; # did I get a hit??
echo $results[0]["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"][0];  #attempt to dump the actual attribute 
?>
```

Comment: what DO you get? I suppose you are getting ```physicaldeliveryofficename```. A ```var_dump($result)`` would be great.

Comment: ( [count] => 1 [0] => Array ( [physicaldeliveryofficename] => Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => Physical Location ) [0] => physicaldeliveryofficename [count] => 1 [dn] => CN=User,OU=Users,OU=Location,OU=Company,OU=_Business Units,DC=PHP,DC=co ) )

Comment: I have made a change... Physicaldeliveryofficename is not always populated, so I would now like to isolate location based on OU=Location in the output above.